# A bag contains 19 blue balls and 11 red balls. 8 balls are drawn from the bag one by one without replacement.

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

A bag contains 19 blue balls and 11 red balls. 8 balls are drawn from the bag one by one without replacement. What is the probability that the 8th ball drawn is red?

I am a bit confused so as to how to approach this problem.
Bcoz I think, how can i calculate what is going to happen 8th draw, unless I have information about what has happen in the last 7 draws...?
Plz explain it ...

Comment: Suppose you drew out all of the balls (i.e., a permutation). What proportion of the permutations are there with a red ball in the $8$th position?

Comment: The end result is that if you have a bag of items and you draw multiple times *with or without* replacement, the probability that the $k$'th draw is of a certain type will be exactly the same as the probability that the *first* draw is of that type.  The answer here is $\frac{11}{30}$.  The information of what the first however many draws were is entirely irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz I guess as per what you said it should be $\frac{11}{30}$ plz correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: @PeterSmith right., I had read 19 total balls, 8 of which red somehow... probably because $19=11+8$

Comment: Okay thank you...